# Android billing exception about a trailing character

Tags: android, exception, android-billing

I get this exception from my crash reports:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.problemio.BillingService@4132b868 with Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED cmp=com.problemio/.BillingService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: utils.Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2376)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: utils.Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19
at utils.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:199)
at utils.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:118)
at com.problemio.BillingService.purchaseStateChanged(BillingService.java:545)
at com.problemio.BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:421)
at com.problemio.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:398)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
... 10 more
Caused by: utils.Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:529)
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:444)
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:390)
at utils.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:189)
... 16 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: utils.Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19
at utils.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:199)
at utils.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:118)
at com.problemio.BillingService.purchaseStateChanged(BillingService.java:545)
at com.problemio.BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:421)
at com.problemio.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:398)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: utils.Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:529)
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:444)
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:390)
at utils.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:189)
... 16 more
utils.Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:529)
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:444)
at utils.Base64.decode(Base64.java:390)
at utils.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:189)
at utils.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:118)
at com.problemio.BillingService.purchaseStateChanged(BillingService.java:545)
at com.problemio.BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:421)
at com.problemio.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:398)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but I don't quite understand what the problem was.  Any suggestions?

It points to this method:

```
  /**
   * Decodes Base64 content using the supplied decodabet and returns
   * the decoded byte array.
   *
   * @param source the Base64 encoded data
   * @param off the offset of where to begin decoding
   * @param len the length of characters to decode
   * @param decodabet the decodabet for decoding Base64 content
   * @return decoded data
   */
  public static byte[] decode(byte[] source, int off, int len, byte[] decodabet)
      throws Base64DecoderException {
    int len34 = len * 3 / 4;
    byte[] outBuff = new byte[2 + len34]; // Upper limit on size of output
    int outBuffPosn = 0;

    byte[] b4 = new byte[4];
    int b4Posn = 0;
    int i = 0;
    byte sbiCrop = 0;
    byte sbiDecode = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      sbiCrop = (byte) (source[i + off] & 0x7f); // Only the low seven bits
      sbiDecode = decodabet[sbiCrop];

      if (sbiDecode >= WHITE_SPACE_ENC) { // White space Equals sign or better
        if (sbiDecode >= EQUALS_SIGN_ENC) {
          // An equals sign (for padding) must not occur at position 0 or 1
          // and must be the last byte[s] in the encoded value
          if (sbiCrop == EQUALS_SIGN) {
            int bytesLeft = len - i;
            byte lastByte = (byte) (source[len - 1 + off] & 0x7f);
            if (b4Posn == 0 || b4Posn == 1) {
              throw new Base64DecoderException(
                  "invalid padding byte '=' at byte offset " + i);
            } else if ((b4Posn == 3 && bytesLeft > 2)
                || (b4Posn == 4 && bytesLeft > 1)) {
              throw new Base64DecoderException(
                  "padding byte '=' falsely signals end of encoded value "
                      + "at offset " + i);
            } else if (lastByte != EQUALS_SIGN && lastByte != NEW_LINE) {
              throw new Base64DecoderException(
                  "encoded value has invalid trailing byte");
            }
            break;
          }

          b4[b4Posn++] = sbiCrop;
          if (b4Posn == 4) {
            outBuffPosn += decode4to3(b4, 0, outBuff, outBuffPosn, decodabet);
            b4Posn = 0;
          }
        }
      } else {
        throw new Base64DecoderException("Bad Base64 input character at " + i
            + ": " + source[i + off] + "(decimal)");
      }
    }

    // Because web safe encoding allows non padding base64 encodes, we
    // need to pad the rest of the b4 buffer with equal signs when
    // b4Posn != 0.  There can be at most 2 equal signs at the end of
    // four characters, so the b4 buffer must have two or three
    // characters.  This also catches the case where the input is
    // padded with EQUALS_SIGN
    if (b4Posn != 0) {
      if (b4Posn == 1) {
        throw new Base64DecoderException("single trailing character at offset "
            + (len - 1));
      }
      b4[b4Posn++] = EQUALS_SIGN;
      outBuffPosn += decode4to3(b4, 0, outBuff, outBuffPosn, decodabet);
    }

    byte[] out = new byte[outBuffPosn];
    System.arraycopy(outBuff, 0, out, 0, outBuffPosn);
    return out;
  }
```

The error seems to be pointing to these lines in my BillingService.java

```
at com.problemio.BillingService.purchaseStateChanged(BillingService.java:585)
at com.problemio.BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:461)
at com.problemio.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:438)
```

The line on 585 is the line

```
purchases = Security.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
```

in this method:

```
private void purchaseStateChanged(int startId, String signedData, String signature) {
    ArrayList<Security.VerifiedPurchase> purchases;
    purchases = Security.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
    if (purchases == null) {
        return;
    }
```

and the line 461 is this line:

```
purchaseStateChanged(startId, signedData, signature);
```

in this method:

```
public void handleCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Consts.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, "handleCommand() action: " + action);
    }
    if (Consts.ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
        String[] notifyIds = intent.getStringArrayExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
        confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
    } else if (Consts.ACTION_GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION.equals(action)) {
        String notifyId = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
        getPurchaseInformation(startId, new String[] { notifyId });
    } else if (Consts.ACTION_PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        String signedData = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNED_DATA);
        String signature = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNATURE);
        purchaseStateChanged(startId, signedData, signature);
    } else if (Consts.ACTION_RESPONSE_CODE.equals(action)) {
        long requestId = intent.getLongExtra(Consts.INAPP_REQUEST_ID, -1);
        int responseCodeIndex = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.INAPP_RESPONSE_CODE,
                ResponseCode.RESULT_ERROR.ordinal());
        ResponseCode responseCode = ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);
        checkResponseCode(requestId, responseCode);
    }
}
```

and line 438 is this line:

```
handleCommand(intent, startId);
```

in this method:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent, startId);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem's not in the code you've included above, but in your (Base64-encoded) public key. I'm not an Android dev, but: is utils.Security part of a third-party billing library? What public key is it passing to `generatePublicKey`?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Android gives a public key to paste into the code.  I pasted and checked that there is no spaces. the utils.Security is part of Android code that they give to process the in-app billing stuff.

Comment: Your Base64 public key is bad. Try to decode it yourself to see. There's lots more that can go wrong with a Base64 string besides embedded spaces.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta interesting...how do I decode it? :) The thing is that I paste it in there not decoded.....maybe thats the problem - maybe I should encode it on my own and paste the encoded string in there?

Comment: Maybe post the code where you use your key. The sample code I've found for `utils.Security.verifyPurchase` passes a Base64 string to `Security.generatePublicKey`. If that matches what you're doing, you definitely need to Base64-encode your PK before dropping it into the class.

Comment: You can use the [`android.util.Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class if you want to experiment.

Comment: Got the same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Does this happen all the time or only one / a few times? The signature you are getting `purchaseStateChanged(startId, signedData, signature)` is also Base64 encoded, and the error says that the encoding is bad. If it only happened once or twice it might be a glitch in the Google Play IAP servers.

Answer (score 1):

For me its happened because i used wrong public key!
Be sure the public key you are using is the public key you`v got from the market.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen the error above when the constructor 
    IabHelper(Context ctx, String base64PublicKey)

is given an incorrect key. 
The solution is:
to go to the Google Play, Developer Console web page.
choose the app, 
then under "Services and APIs" you'll see "Your license key for this application"
use that string.

---

Another solution is to go into the Security.java file and make a couple of changes. See the lines on which I have the comment "// ADD_THIS_LINE"

```
    public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
    if (signedData == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "data is null");
        return false;
    }

    boolean verified = false;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
        PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);

        if( key != null) // ADD_THIS_LINE
            verified = Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);

        if (!verified) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signature does not match data.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}    
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  :     :     
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
        return null;  // ADD_THIS_LINE
        // COMMENT_OUT_THIS_LINE:   throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: All you are doing with the line you added is skipping signature check if you don't have a key, making this fail silently instead.